# Picker View uncaught exception SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Hello I am a beginner at SWIFT and I have an issue with my project : I have a picker View on one of my View controller and I think that I have connected all outlets but when I execute the code and test my app on the emulator it comes an error when I click on the button (on the previous View) that has to open the view in which my picker View is set. When I get rid of my the picker View from the View controller, there is no more error.
The fact is that I have watched every tutorials on PickerView and did all they shew ...

I don't know where comes from my mistake.

I let some screen shots to be clearer

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don’t post images for code, insert it into the question. It is easier to read and reproduce. Also state the error in your question, not in an image. Take a look at some of the upvoted questions to see how to form a good question and read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also don't post images of stack traces. Copy and paste the error into your question. And your image doesn't show the important part of the stack trace - the top and the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't store the created picker view instance. You instantiate it inside of a function, assign the delegate and dataSource and then you don't store it in your class. So the ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) releases it, because it thinks the instance is not longer needed. Just create a variable in your `PickerController` and store as long as the view controller is alive.

The second problem is that you actually want to see the picker view, so you need to add it to the view controller's view. You might need to position it right or use layout constraints (Search for Auto Layout).

```
var pickerView: UIPickerView!

func createPickerView() {
    pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(pickerView)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and sorry for the uncommon way to ask question. It's my first time here ;)

Comment: @RomainPeres No need to apologize. Simply edit your question and replace the images with copied and pasted text.